# VPS: Disaster recovery

Tags: server, backup

I have a live vps running ubuntu `12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin)`, and though I have all of our web application's databases backed up to the amazon s3, and all of our source code backed up on bitbucket and local development machines, I still want to keep downtime down to a minimum in the event of some unprecedented and catastrophic system failure.

Really, what I need is maybe an application that clones my Ubuntu server as a disk image or a similar format every x amount of seconds, which can then be downloaded to my local machine, or uploaded to another vps. Maybe it could do this in a `git` sort of way, similar to Mac OSX' time machine, so only changes to the system are saved and uploaded, and my bandwidth isn't used up uploading every last bit of information to another location, over and over again.

I'd also want to use this disc image if were to move hosts. I'd like to be able to back up my local ubuntu installation with it too.

Or does Ubuntu include some command line tools that make this backup process less daunting? Will I be able to write a script myself that calls some commands to backup my vps?

I know of Ubuntu One and the Ubuntu's backup application on my local machine, so is there a CLI equivalent for my server?

I'm prepared to change my ubuntu installation to > 13 if it means these tools will be available.

Now, when Windows goes funny, your best bet is to nuke it and reinstall everything. But Ubuntu is far superior :D , so could I use this backup process without fear of bugs and corruption and other nasties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, I can recommend creating a disaster plan that you (or somebody else, in the case of your death - yeah, it's serious stuff) can completely rebuild the asset from backups if the main server (and you) were hit by a meteor.

In most cases you're actually not going to want image backups. They're hard to use in a VPS environment because you lack access... And anything your VPS provides might die when they're hit by the meteor.

My disaster plan with one of my clients involves the following items:

- Get backup from S3.
- Install Ubuntu (latest LTS) with a VPS and then log in as root.
- Copy backup to SSH location (with basic instructions)
- Run a script that was included in your backup. This unpacks, sets permissions, creates the right users, applies security, etc.
- Fix your DNS (include details) to point to new IP.

It's a lot of work. And it's important that you test it too. Follow all of it (except the DNS) to the letter and if you're left with anything but a functioning server at the end of it, you need to go back and improve things.

And you need to keep testing it. At least every LTS release you need to go back and check that it all still works. That your backups are being created in the right way.

You can assume a *certain* level of competency in the person following the instructions (you can assume your company hires somebody with *some* training and you can explain in the document what people will need to know how to do in order to execute your commands) but it's very important that you mention everything that isn't completely standard.

---

In a non-disaster scenario, it's also good to have these sorts of scripts (and documentation) around if you want to move something on a server to another server. It let you know what's what very quickly without having to spend hours working out why you've got three separate copies of nginx running on a single server.

Comment: I also don't think there's much difference in time. Restoring from a scripted backup takes me about 10 minutes. About a minute to get a new VPS up and running, a few minutes to copy off S3 and a few minutes for it to run and reboot. DNS is the slowest bit to update but that's largely unavoidable in a serious disaster.